# Swift How to get data from firebase before page loads

Tags: swift, firebase

I have this firebase code.

```
self.db.collection("ustas").getDocuments(){ (querysnapshot,err) in
         for document in querysnapshot!.documents {

         }                
}
```

Here I basically get all the documents from `ustas` collection. Now I have to present it in a List view. I tried, first creating a function before body and assiging all the values to a variable and then iterating thourhg the variable. Like this:

```
@State var ustasList: Array<Usta> = []
    
    func getUstalar() -> Array<Usta>{
        var templist: Array<Usta> = []
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.db.collection("ustas").getDocuments(){ (querysnapshot,err) in
                for document in querysnapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let newUsta = Usta(id: UUID(), name: data["name"] as! String, type: data["type"] as! String,telephone: data["telephone"] as! String)
                    templist.append(newUsta)
                }
           }
        }
        return templist
    }



var body: some View {
   NavigationView{
         List{
                ForEach(0..<self.ustasList.count){ i in
                    Text(self.ustasList[i].name)
                }
            }
   } 
    .onAppear(){
        self.ustasList = self.getUstalar()
    }
  }
```

But it didn't work, because `return templist` executed before the getDocuments() could. Then I tried putting the firebase code inside List, like this:

```
 List{
                self.db.collection("ustas").getDocuments(){ (querysnapshot,err) in
                     for document in querysnapshot!.documents {
                         let data = document.data()
                         Text(data["name"])
                     }
                }
            }
```

But it gave me the `Type 'Void' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`. How can I do this in Swift properly?

Comment: A few things. You're going to want to load your dataSource from Firebase after the view loads but before the UI updates so the data will be available when its time to present it. You can remove `DispatchQueue.main.async` as Firebase is asynchronous and data loads in the background. This `return templist` is going to be called before your firebase data is loaded; as mentioned, Firebase is async. So. you need to populate the dataSource within the Firebase closure, then refresh your view to present the data. In other words, after this `for document` loop, within the closure, refresh the UI

Comment: You could conceivably put the code to load from firebase in the views .onAppear function but it depends  on what the rest of the code sequence is.

Answer (score 0):

`getUstalar` is an async function, so it cannot return the values synchronously with `self.ustasList = self.getUstalar()` - this will just return `[]`

Add the elements directly to `self.ustasList` inside the completion handler of `getDocuments`:

```
@State var ustasList: [Usta] = []

func getUstalar() {
   self.db.collection("ustas").getDocuments(){ (querysnapshot,err) in
      for document in querysnapshot!.documents {
         let data = document.data()
         let newUsta = Usta(id: UUID(), name: data["name"] as! String, type: data["type"] as! String,telephone: data["telephone"] as! String)

         self.ustasList.append(newUsta) // populate the list
      }
   }
}
```

And invoke this function in `.onAppear` - it'll populate the list:

```
var body: some Body {
   NavigationView {
      // ...
   }.onAppear(){
       self.getUstalar()
   }
}
```